# The right way to close ssh connection when using pexpect?

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect, winpexpect

I use Python pexpect (and winpexpect) for an executing of the commands by ssh

```
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    pexpectmodname = "winpexpect"
    from winpexpect import winspawn as spawn
else:
    pexpectmodname = "pexpect"
    from pexpect import spawn

pexpectmod = __import__(pexpectmodname)

...

# connect
shellCmd = "ssh %s %d -l %s %s" % (portParam, port, username, server.host)
self.spawn = spawn(shellCmd, timeout=self.timeout, env=os.environ, ignore_sighup=False)

...
# DO WORK WITH SSH
...

# close ssh connection #1 (send exit)
self.spawn.sendline('exit')
index = self.spawn.expect([pexpectmod.EOF, "(?i)there are stopped jobs"])
if index == 1:
    self.spawn.sendline("exit")
    self.spawn.expect([pexpect.EOF])

# close ssh connection #2 (check isalive, send exit and close)
if self.spawn.isalive():
    self.spawn.sendline('exit')
    self.spawn.close()

# close ssh connection #3 (send sigkill)
import signal
self.spawn.kill(signal.SIGKILL)
```

How to close the self.spawn to make sure that the ssh session is closed?
What way is crossplatform for Windows and UNIX?

Answer (score 3):

The elegant way is to send `exit\r` or `CTRL-D` and wait for `EOF`. But it's also fine to simply exit the script (Expect, pexpect or winexpect) after you've done with the SSH session and don't care about the exit status of the SSH session. When the script exits (not matter if it's clean or not), the OS kernel would close the SSH session (the TCP connection) for you. The SSH server would not complain about this.

`pexpect.spawn.close()` would close the pty which in turn would send `SIGHUP` to the shell which in turn would terminate (kill) the shell unless the shell is ignoring `SIGHUP`. It's like you close the `PuTTY` (or `gnome-terminal`, ...) window when the shell is still running.

#### UPDATE:

The above statements suppose all the applications (Expect, pexpect, winexpect and SSH server) are well implemented. I have a system (ESXi) on which the SSH **server** failed to reclaim allocated PTYs when the SSH connection was not cleanly closed. So after some time I can no longer get a PTY though the SSH auth is successful.

Comment: Thanks! I asked this question because I had many losted ssh connection when my script failed. I found this topic https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/136 and it help me, but I want to know "How right way for closing ssh connection with using pexpect".

Comment: I understood that it is goot to send 'exit' but I didn't understand I need call self.spawn.close() after it or no?

Comment: `.close()` would close the *pty* which in turn would send *SIGHUP* to the shell which in turn would terminate (kill) the shell. It's like you close the PuTTY (or gnome-terminal, ...) window when the shell is still running.

Answer (score -1):

If your aim is just executing commands through SSH, you could also consider using [*Paramiko*](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/index.html):

```
import paramiko

# Create a new client
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
# Connect to your remote
client.connect('127.0.0.1', username='john', password='doe')

# Execute a command
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("pwd")

# Do anything you want with `stdout` and `stderr`
# Execute as many other commands as you want

# When you are done, close your connection
client.close()
```

It is a pure Python package and worked very well whenever I used it.